# MySql IN Parameter - Does a VarChar IN Parameter val need to be single quoted when used in Stored Procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, asp-classic

MySql IN Parameter - Does a VarChar IN Parameter val need to be single quoted when used in Stored Procedure?

I have created my classic ASP code just like normal but I am not getting the column to update.

Do I need to quote a VarChar parameter?

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `usp_update_map_record` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`ddddddd`@`%` PROCEDURE `usp_update_map_record`(
  IN p_intGrillId INT(10),
  IN p_intPartId INT(10),
  IN p_ManRef VARCHAR(10)
)
BEGIN

UPDATE parts_map SET manualref = 'p_ManRef' WHERE grillid = p_intGrillId AND partid = p_intPartId;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

VBSCRIPT PORTION:

```
With comm
    .ActiveConnection = conn
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "usp_update_map_record"
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("p_intGrillId", adInteger, adParamInput, 10, intGrillId)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("p_intPartId", adInteger, adParamInput, 10, CIntPartId)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("p_ManRef", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, strManualRef)
    .Execute
End With
```

Also I tested all 3 values and they are not empty.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
UPDATE parts_map SET manualref = 'p_ManRef'
                                 ^--      ^--
```

The quotes turn that "field" into a string. - you're not comparing two fields, you're comparing the manualref field against a string whose value happens to be the NAME of a parameter for your sproc.

Try:

```
UPDATE parts_map SET manualref = @p_ManRef
                                 ^--- variable/parameter indicator
```

Comment: Hi I tried the parameter indiator but I am still not getting an update. I will edit my question with the ASP portion.

Comment: My bad, I was not passing an id value after all... sorry, I will give you the answer because I want to use variable/parameter indicators.